# RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine

Tags: python, asyncio, fastapi

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_connection(
    postgres: Postgresql = postgresql,
) -> Cursor:
    """Get async connection to postgresql of pool."""

    async with postgres.get_connect() as connection:
        async with (await connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)) as c:
            yield c


class Postgresql(BaseConnector):
    uri: str
    pool: typing.Optional[typing.AsyncContextManager[aiopg.Pool]] = None

    def __init__(self, uri: str):
        self.uri = uri

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def get_connect(self) -> typing.AsyncIterator[Connection]:
        if self.pool is None:
            self.pool = aiopg.create_pool(dsn=self.uri)

        async with self.pool as pool:
            async with pool.acquire() as conn:
                yield conn


class UserRepository:
    @classmethod
    @collect_response
    async def create(cls, cmd: models.CreateUserCommand) -> models.User:
        q = f"""
                insert into users(
                    uid, username, password
                ) values (
                    '{uuid4()}',
                    %(username)s,
                    %(password)s
                )
                returning uid, username, password;
            """
        async with get_connection() as c:
            await c.execute(q, cmd.to_dict(show_secrets=True))
            return await c.fetchone()


@router.post(
    "/",
    response_model=models.User,
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
    summary="Create user",
    response_model_exclude={"password"},
)
async def create_user(
        cmd: models.CreateUserCommand
) -> Any:
    await cmd.set_hash_password()
    return await UserRepository.create(cmd=cmd)
```

Почему не работает?, срабатывает только один раз
Полный трейс ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/__main__.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
    └ <function main at 0x1005884a0>

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/__main__.py", line 8, in main
    uvicorn.run(
    │       └ <function run at 0x1017d7ce0>
    └ <module 'uvicorn' from '/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/__init__.py'>

  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 569, in run
    server.run()
    │      └ <function Server.run at 0x1019056c0>
    └ <uvicorn.server.Server object at 0x101ff3b50>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           │       │   │    │             └ None
           │       │   │    └ <function Server.serve at 0x101905760>
           │       │   └ <uvicorn.server.Server object at 0x101ff3b50>
           │       └ <function run at 0x1010b8fe0>
           └ <module 'asyncio' from '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyn...

  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           │      │   └ <coroutine object Server.serve at 0x101f6b120>
           │      └ <function Runner.run at 0x101150b80>
           └ <asyncio.runners.Runner object at 0x1025ccf50>

  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           │    │     │                  └ <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<Server.serve() running at /Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-pac...
           │    │     └ <method 'run_until_complete' of 'uvloop.loop.Loop' objects>
           │    └ <uvloop.Loop running=True closed=False debug=False>
           └ <asyncio.runners.Runner object at 0x1025ccf50>

> File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
                   └ <uvicorn.middleware.proxy_headers.ProxyHeadersMiddleware object at 0x1040559d0>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
                 │    │   │      │        └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.send of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289d0>>
                 │    │   │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
                 │    │   └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
                 │    └ <fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at 0x104045290>
                 └ <uvicorn.middleware.proxy_headers.ProxyHeadersMiddleware object at 0x1040559d0>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
                           │      │        └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.send of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289d0>>
                           │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
                           └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
          │    │                │      │        └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.send of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289d0>>
          │    │                │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
          │    │                └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
          │    └ <starlette.middleware.errors.ServerErrorMiddleware object at 0x10406acd0>
          └ <fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at 0x104045290>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
          │    │   │      │        └ <function ServerErrorMiddleware.__call__.<locals>._send at 0x10443dbc0>
          │    │   │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
          │    │   └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
          │    └ <starlette.middleware.exceptions.ExceptionMiddleware object at 0x10406ab10>
          └ <starlette.middleware.errors.ServerErrorMiddleware object at 0x10406acd0>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
          │    │   │      │        └ <function ExceptionMiddleware.__call__.<locals>.sender at 0x10443dd00>
          │    │   │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
          │    │   └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
          │    └ <fastapi.middleware.asyncexitstack.AsyncExitStackMiddleware object at 0x10406ae50>
          └ <starlette.middleware.exceptions.ExceptionMiddleware object at 0x10406ab10>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
          │    │   │      │        └ <function ExceptionMiddleware.__call__.<locals>.sender at 0x10443dd00>
          │    │   │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
          │    │   └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
          │    └ <fastapi.routing.APIRouter object at 0x1038e1c90>
          └ <fastapi.middleware.asyncexitstack.AsyncExitStackMiddleware object at 0x10406ae50>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
          │     │      │      │        └ <function ExceptionMiddleware.__call__.<locals>.sender at 0x10443dd00>
          │     │      │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
          │     │      └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
          │     └ <function Route.handle at 0x102a73560>
          └ APIRoute(path='/api/user/', name='create_user', methods=['POST'])
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
          │    │   │      │        └ <function ExceptionMiddleware.__call__.<locals>.sender at 0x10443dd00>
          │    │   │      └ <bound method RequestResponseCycle.receive of <uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl.RequestResponseCycle object at 0x1044289...
          │    │   └ {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8000), 'cl...
          │    └ <function request_response.<locals>.app at 0x10405b420>
          └ APIRoute(path='/api/user/', name='create_user', methods=['POST'])
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
                     │    └ <starlette.requests.Request object at 0x1044287d0>
                     └ <function get_request_handler.<locals>.app at 0x10405b4c0>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                         └ <function run_endpoint_function at 0x102a71940>
  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
                 │         │      └ {'cmd': CreateUserCommand(username='varick', password='$2b$12$q0QZ2KYHjvVgOWUE4wLP0uAloz3ARZG3opt37hxmHEhggVZ6Tctdu')}
                 │         └ <function create_user at 0x1038a2de0>
                 └ <fastapi.dependencies.models.Dependant object at 0x104068bd0>

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/web/api/user/views.py", line 24, in create_user
    return await UserRepository.create(cmd=cmd)
                 │              │          └ CreateUserCommand(username='varick', password='$2b$12$q0QZ2KYHjvVgOWUE4wLP0uAloz3ARZG3opt37hxmHEhggVZ6Tctdu')
                 │              └ <classmethod(<function UserRepository.create at 0x1038a3060>)>
                 └ <class 'victory.db.repository.user.UserRepository'>

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/db/repository/handlers/handle_exception.py", line 28, in wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
                 │     │       └ {'cmd': CreateUserCommand(username='varick', password='$2b$12$q0QZ2KYHjvVgOWUE4wLP0uAloz3ARZG3opt37hxmHEhggVZ6Tctdu')}
                 │     └ (<class 'victory.db.repository.user.UserRepository'>,)
                 └ <function collect_response.<locals>.inner at 0x1038a2fc0>

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/db/repository/handlers/collect_response.py", line 35, in inner
    response = await fn(*args, **kwargs)
                     │   │       └ {'cmd': CreateUserCommand(username='varick', password='$2b$12$q0QZ2KYHjvVgOWUE4wLP0uAloz3ARZG3opt37hxmHEhggVZ6Tctdu')}
                     │   └ (<class 'victory.db.repository.user.UserRepository'>,)
                     └ <function UserRepository.create at 0x1038a2f20>

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/db/repository/user.py", line 26, in create
    async with get_connection() as c:
               └ <function get_connection at 0x102f70400>

  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 204, in __aenter__
    return await anext(self.gen)
                       │    └ <async_generator object get_connection at 0x104077a40>
                       └ <contextlib._AsyncGeneratorContextManager object at 0x1040ab550>

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/db/repository/connection.py", line 18, in get_connection
    async with postgres.get_connect() as connection:
               │        └ <function Postgresql.get_connect at 0x1038a1120>
               └ <victory.db.connectors.postgresql.Postgresql object at 0x1025a1290>

  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 204, in __aenter__
    return await anext(self.gen)
                       │    └ <async_generator object Postgresql.get_connect at 0x104075140>
                       └ <contextlib._AsyncGeneratorContextManager object at 0x1040ab2d0>

  File "/Users/eric/projects/test-task-for-victory/victory/db/connectors/postgresql.py", line 25, in get_connect
    async with self.pool as pool:
               │    └ <aiopg.utils._ContextManager object at 0x1038d1180>
               └ <victory.db.connectors.postgresql.Postgresql object at 0x1025a1290>

  File "/Users/eric/venvs/victory-odDYh4YD-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiopg/utils.py", line 82, in __aenter__
    self._obj = await self._coro
    │    │            │    └ <member '_coro' of '_ContextManager' objects>
    │    │            └ <aiopg.utils._ContextManager object at 0x1038d1180>
    │    └ <member '_obj' of '_ContextManager' objects>
    └ <aiopg.utils._ContextManager object at 0x1038d1180>

RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
```

Comment: Такое впечатление, что `postgres.get_connect()` можно только один раз получить ("заэвэйтить"). Я бы попробовал как-то асинхронный кэш где-то прикрутить (типа https://github.com/aio-libs/async-lru), чтобы подключение один раз только создавалось.

Comment: @insolor как думаете, надо на такой вопрос ставить тревогу на счет "почему этот код не работает"?

Comment: @nchistov, скорее всего нет, тут вроде бы код достаточно полный, и ошибка с полным трэйсбэком (чего почти никогда у новых участников не бывает, по крайней мере это достаточно редко), в принципе я не вижу с вопросом особых проблем.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, я пока ещё не очень в этом разбираюсь!

Comment: По вопросу: хотя нет, тут с `async with self.pool as pool:` проблема, похоже что нельзя два раза один и тот же pull "дернуть" через `async with`

Comment: @insolor нет, так вообще не работает, пишет что объект не поддерживает синхронный менеджер контекста

Comment: Как догадка: возможно строка `async with self.pool as pool:` не нужна, попробуйте в следующей строке брать `self.pool`: `async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:`. Если не поможет, придется глубже копать.

Comment: @insolor нет, AttributeError: '_ContextManager' object has no attribute 'acquire'

Comment: Смотрите, create_pool создает контекстный менеджер пула, который при входе в `async with` создает новый пул, при выходе из блока - закрывает и уничтожает его. При этом этот контекст менеджер похоже одноразовый, в него нельзя два раза войти. Простое решение ошибки - каждый раз создавать новый менеджер контекста пула, а не сохранять в self.pool и переиспользовать. Более сложное - вручную создавать Pool через Pool.from_pool_fill, потом закрывать как тут в функции `_destroy_pool`: https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/aiopg/pool.html

Comment: В промежутке между вызовами сохранять созданный Pool в вашем объекте Postgresql. Но правда не совсем понятно, в какой момент должно уничтожение пула срабатывать.

Comment: @insolor каждый раз создавать новый менеджер контекста пула - так работает, спасибо. как временное решение пойдет